# NPN transistor turning on with grounded base

Tags: transistors, h-bridge, npn

The NPN transistor in bottom left with grounded base is turning on in circuit simulator for some reason.

Can someone tell me why is this happening?

[Circuit Simulation link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWKIAsBmET2YKYFowwAoAE3BRRACYVJzKwB2ANmpBJwDMBDAVwBsALqXog0kBhWq02HHgOGCQzSlUZUQATlZqNdCHjTRGCZozRgEADkgJNVTWGZ7oVu3bfNLTKmnvg4di4%20ISIlNAQNXTEqOmj9EENjKicEMCtmBDRGHKtGKFcPCxQEdAQcrwgwQLkQxWVVSCstHSbkAjFoSNpSsDRmNHQKDTwYN21LdUsUFUgHALpahTCxSOo2tFj15roOowRrMzc-GfScylHCzSs0KzBaGypylGbqxeDlsmiaOPVwFlkH1CXz%204lUfx%20gPkoQATv8dDJIZD9HAiAB3FrgfzaeFQdGYpise4MAGQfGbfT%20Cm4skY6mE6h-Bm0zFUKzNHFgvEYzkSURclnRLnUgXkrbCrZsnZEADm2zEfNizWpdEFoMVGz5LOJCsayq1RAASvKGUrwGzkHQZJpLQUEPidaa2sz8dEna9SUQ4TNVDIIlEZHFYl7Ei9pHQVOHkFRg3S1mb-VGWSgnJiU0SLWTjbRfhoKM14sgZEhVXb8TiY5QK4HyzpTKyazyEfopMixUHKNS23TJfWu42YnFERCa3KCDo-ngw4WWZGzXOB-mQDZUGHCHoHQDITru1GkSPVfipwWZMfwGANxiz%20uozfBTIb0jFwurZHE8m32sGe-N6xE6aazhcdGQ0Oc-hRVE4UTaIcxA5A3jJIA)

[image: circuit schematic]

I know why the other 3 transistors are turning on. I am not using this circuit instead this one [h bridge](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWKIDMAOESAsLMFMBaMMAKABNwssQAmLSS6sAdgDZaQy8AzAQwFcANgBdyjVJCZVa9Dlz5DRwkK2o1mNEAE526zQwgxWKFJDBaakFAgRhrNLVGjMsGhBpootxBFdxg4Th4BERJle1oNVEtI-XAQAjRoYwDmMw1ILQsUZicaBHyzNFZIBG9MgP9A%20RClFTVIDB1aRuQiECTWGho0SSoUS1YtAoSYGi7h5gQUVQG0HRxwauDFMNQRywwBhk22iAIjU2ZjlCxeyE8wIdHnV0tpsAfzeYgAhhrVij0ZHaiWXSCClCXyipjUUToO0BtRIAHdtOxzJpmv8oHCEeA2OJUZB0dtwBZogYsbj4fjUd8cejmj0muwwWj4c0GWBpAzSbEJNR8ey8TEGfjaWiAOYtLaSMVE5Ac74M3a8%20Gs7kS%20US3EAJUlFNaYB60pAskcDGN0AQ6KVmN0OpJ6MpWN2VIATgaBpKIrsDPASM6iFaMKpJZ64OicJpiJpQ4Hqbo6BjIYy4wh2DTZByUwZpPGOYLY4LU3ydkmpVmCz9OSX4QRXeGXWHdQmKbILRWy-HviWfWdaEXXfl2EHg1hHpbW7Is054BcstOZ7OtLkAnk8kgYPB%207A4Au0QBlA0BvuYTNF40gPiCADOeGQNBIu4IXYPRD1B4Mp94F6vOxImqfGHjv4JOIGFkFdpVNb9DzUEDpCRfUQP1GAzVFADvgA9kRUgzkEDZNU0XCNA1B7DZj3iRJnEgDQUHMLxLHyKYbm6cZvGsaxnnQBdliBOpeyLfcSMMU0ulYNA0A0O5WOkIwsAsNAchsTJ51Yei3mhVZnXQQj2CwPj%20yWL1K2resq00bpqA5YzaFjfdYw5azqH3fMyQ2WR3RsvENljKg-zc%20EvMs6g-OaDlAvYX0MXMq4MTCj10XvP8izi1AZjRTstmS10TF0t5g1FDT1k0PKZgwY01giTLUAIpKsqcdxrCsTwhmYeYaEiow-DsFx6F8FgvD01TQjJAr0pGcrs0qnlKpfEggA)

Answer (score 2):

Initially it looked like the simulator was showing the current flowing in the wrong direction.  I removed your voltage source and ground, then added new ones and it worked correctly, the transistor was not turned on like in the simulation you posted.  However, when I exported a link it started to behaved incorrectly as yours did.

Looks like it is a bug in the simulator.

[simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWK0BsAmBAWA7HAnAmHgMwrHEiYVJUgICmAtGGAFAAm4mmIamkXHmGwpeIdvQBmAQwCuAGwAuHQSGKQh3XvzESZC5YpAoeabGhB5RZiwIiMAHNCstMYKg4fq0FPLBSu7sReDnhoBEx44HDiUnJKrEbECBY2amgCaXbI6KRuWOEZCA7myOZgDnAo2HgOmA4IKCgO0QJ68YbGppAtVrw9UCDMQzDNNcSYjQh42NjTGiPQ5tUkLJUO6BUtYDHtBolqKf0txBnHg8NOG%20EOPj14YcEtjDCQT8UIWJA1ZMRgFjs2nF9pw0nxMqVhNZYvoEqDSupTKVwbpgQkAE7gETaTI6FF2OCsADullERAsfShUGJpKxZK0VMgNNOdjC6Ts2KZJJZdN4kM5NL6aE8tMR1JJfTF7h4Yq5fIsYp5suZZ0VZ2FLTlaTFGROCzl0rUC11Rp4BoZ2JNjJpaSpVoFmMwJhxh1SOkyGVYmMY9RdzvxvE93KOJuSboETIASpQYmluC0soMdEgI8gEILrHxafiM7xGtn3bmUYac9z1VmeaX2XnRJXC2XcRDw9SAOZDMDWUo%20hOlCM0-0Df313nFrRVlET5HD7sumcsWw0uf-F3z8Ur5cT4dO0w6beutd7sO8o8G7FHu2F70d%20VdG8EwmYo9x2O91pRm92kX-TVJgRRVMwOmbaGlKWgntSQA)

Comment: Well no current flow is not in wrong direction just decrease the simulation speed to make it fluent then it will not appear to be moving in wrong direction, I am not accepting the answer as I will check the circuit in other simulators to check if it was a bug when I get back my laptop next month